# Synology NAS Default IP Address

Tags: installation, nas, synology

My work recently purchased a Synology DS3617xs NAS. How do I find the default IP of the NAS so I can do the initial setup?

- For security, we're running on a closed system - no internet
- Running RHEL 7.4, so the Synology Assistant won't work (Win /Mac /Debian only)
- We have two switches but no routers, so no DHCP

From the documentation it seems you need either an internet connection or DHCP for automatic IP assignment (where you can then find the IP from your router).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a work-around.

I connected the NAS directly to my workstation using another LAN port I have installed on my workstation. I set the IPv4 connection for this port as Link-Local Only. When the LAN port identified its IP address, I used nmap to search the network to find other IP addresses. Since the only other item on this connection was the Synology, I was able to figure out the IP.

Comment: What is "link-local only" and how do you enable it on Windows 11?

Comment: @rollsch Try this link (https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/q2vm4u/synology_maping_network_drive_with_windows_11/?rdt=44809), or this one (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/715326/i-cant-access-my-synology-nas-dsm-from-windows-11)

Answer (score 0):

As you dont have DCHP option, please check the subnet and IP Range of the Switches. Then set the IP for the synology diskstation manually (search with the App Synology Assistant [Windows download Link](https://global.synologydownload.com/download/Utility/Assistant/7.0.4-50051/Windows/synology-assistant-7.0.4-50051.exe)). Run synology assist from your computer makes sure the NAS is up and running all lights on and the blue light solid. LAN and disk lights should be flashing. It does take a few minutes for the unit to become available the first time. if you see the IP you can just type in the IP and get to you NAS as well without the synology assistant. You will need just the DSM file for your version/ unit. usually xxx.PAT. its that easy . Maybe the extra switch is the problem.

Pat file of your Diskstation: [Link](https://global.download.synology.com/download/DSM/release/6.2.1/23824/DSM_DS3617xs_23824.pat)

Comment: The Synology Assistant won't work on Red Hat systems.

Comment: generic download link https://www.synology.com/pl-pl/support/download

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it will spend time looking for a DHCP server to allocate an IP, and if it can't it'll eventually(*) default back to a self assigned IP in the 169.254.x.x range.

It takes quite a while to time out, so if you want to set it up without a DHCP server, you need to power it up and wait for 10+ minutes till it times out looking for DHCP responses.

IF you want to set it up without DHCP, you'll want to ensure your computers IP is setup to be able to talk to this range.  (eg set your netmask to 0.0.0.0 so all traffic is sent directly, instead of any configured gateway)

Answer (score 0):

An update for those coming in from the future :)

All you need is actually just a device connected to the same network as the Synology NAS, so long as it has a browser with JavaScript — aye, any smartphone will do.

If you have no connection to the Internet (which was the case of the OP), put the following URL on the browser:

[synologynas:5000](http://synologynas:5000)
([synologynas.local:5000](http://synologynas.local:5000) on an Apple device)

If you *do* have Internet connection, but you're forced to go through an (internal) Web proxy server, then the command above might not work, in which case you should simply go to the following URL:

https://finds.synology.com/

It should just take a few seconds to find your NAS (on my network, it takes around 4-5 seconds) and give you its IP address, with a button at the end saying "Connect", something like this (my IP address is redacted for privacy reasons):

[image: Find Your Synology NAS]

There is no need to install anything on your system, no matter what hardware or operating system it runs on, although the device should at least have a graphics display, a JS-capable browser, and a means to type an URL in it — those are the only three requirements. You might even be able to use a smartwatch or SmartTV. A smartphone will most certainly work!

**Source:** [Synology Knowledge Center — "How do I find my Synology NAS via Web Assistant or Synology Assistant?"](https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/Unable_to_Locate_NAS)